# How can i read Bill of materials report data in tekla structure using .NET

Tags: c#, .net

In tekla structure 2020, I open a model. So in the tekla structure open document manager and go to assembly drawing and open a drawing in down you will see a Bill of Materials report. So using .NET I am trying to read that report.

```cs
// Open the interface, get the current drawing and loop through all the views in the drawing.
DrawingHandler DrawingHandler = new DrawingHandler();

if (DrawingHandler.GetConnectionStatus())
{
    Drawing CurrentDrawing = DrawingHandler.GetActiveDrawing();
    Tekla.Structures.Drawing.UI.Picker picker = DrawingHandler.GetPicker();

    if (CurrentDrawing != null)
    {
        DrawingObjectEnumerator Enum = CurrentDrawing.GetSheet().GetViews();

        while (Enum.MoveNext())
        {
            Tekla.Structures.Drawing.View View = Enum.Current as Tekla.Structures.Drawing.View;
            // Perform actions for the view here.
        }
    }
}
```

So here using tekla structure API I am trying to read that drawing.so in that CurrentDrawing I am getting that drawing but don't know how to read that bill of Materials report.
In bill od materials have multiple item mark their profile size there length etc.

So I am trying to read the bill of materials values. But don't know how I will do that.